# Problem with SQLite.swift after migration to Swift 5

Tags: sqlite.swift, swift5

I use SQLite.swift and after upgrading to Swift 5 an error appears in the library. Please help me rewrite the method.

Error:

```
'withUnsafeBytes' is deprecated: use `withUnsafeBytes<R>(_: (UnsafeRawBufferPointer) throws -> R) rethrows -> R` instead
```

Code:

```
public var datatypeValue: Blob {
    return withUnsafeBytes { (pointer: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) -> Blob in
        return Blob(bytes: pointer, length: count)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Till `SQLite.swift` doesn't release any update with the fix you could try modify manually the `SQLite/Foundation.swift` for `fromDatatypeValue(_ dataValue: Blob)` function and the computed property `datatypeValue` in this way:

```
public static func fromDatatypeValue(_ dataValue: Blob) -> Data {
    return Data(dataValue.bytes)
}

public var datatypeValue: Blob {
    return withUnsafeBytes { (pointer: UnsafeRawBufferPointer) -> Blob in
        return Blob(bytes: pointer.baseAddress!, length: count)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works great.