# Xcode 10.2 Update SQLite.Swift framework by stephencelis doesn't work

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode10.2

I updated my Xcode awhile ago and my queries don't seem to work anymore.

I use SQLite.Swift framework by stephencelis

Comment: Then contact the creator/maintainer of the framework about it instead of posting a notice (I see no question asked here) about it on stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They haven't updated the lib for Swift 5. You can make a request on github currently it's compatible for Swift 4.2 so you either need to downgrade Xcode version to 10.1 or request them.

Screenshot of current github page:
[image: Screenshot of current github page]

Answer (score 0):

Till `SQLite.swift` doesn't release any update, you could try to modify 
the library manually. Solution here: [Problem with SQLite.swift after migration to Swift 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55570433/problem-with-sqlite-swift-after-migration-to-swift-5/55592883)